# Store 1 TO 10 in 5 bytes in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I'm a newbie in assembly language.
I'm trying to store 1 to 10 in order using four bit integers to take up at most 5 bytes which is 40 bits and I have to use binary initializer. Is there any one who give me some help?
I dont know how to initialize binary in assembly. thank you

The architecture that I use is x86.

Comment: Erm...if you don't know assembly, why do you have to use it?

Comment: What architecture? Where's your code so far?

Comment: The architecture that I use is x86.

Comment: To store integer from 1 to 10 all you need is 4 bits, or 1 byte at most. Why do you need 5 bytes?

Comment: @mvp: 1 to 10, in order.  10 numbers * 4 bits each = 40 bits = 5 bytes.

Comment: @cHao It is a part of my assembly class and I'm confused with this part. I've been studying assembly for 2 weeks.

Comment: @femchi: And where's your code so far?  What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
 byte <someconstant>
```

(assuming your assembler has a "byte" psuedo-op. If you don't know if your assembler has this, then you aren't ready to write any assembly language at all).  Example:

```
 byte 12h
```

From this, you should be able to solve your problem, unless your teacher wants you to write code to construct the byte values.  Then the following hint should help:

```
 mov   al, 10h
 mov   ah, 02h
 add   al, ah
 mov   target_location, al
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: uh, thanks for pointing out a stupid mistake. Even self-appointed experts trip over their shoelaces sometimes.

Comment: this is what I've got so far 
Variablename BYTE 0001b,10b,11b,100b,101b,110b,111b,1000b,1001b,1010b

Comment: @femchi: You're beginning to get the idea, but you have *10* bytes here, and your teacher wanted 5 bytes containing 2 pairs of 4 bits.

Comment: @cHao BITE TEXTEQU <BYTE>

Answer (score 1):

Numbers BYTE 00010010b,00110100b,01010110b,01111000b,10011010b